# Google App Engine Bounce notification not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

I am sending email with Google App Engine through my custom domain admin@codeavengers.com.

I want to receive bounce notifications but can't seem to get it working.

I have the following code in appengine-web.xml

```
  <inbound-services>
    <service>channel_presence</service>
    <service>mail_bounce</service>
  </inbound-services>
```

web.xml contains:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>bouncehandler</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.codeavengers.BounceHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>bouncehandler</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/bounce</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And BounceHandlerServlet contains...

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,
                   HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    log.severe("BounceHandler triggered");
}
```

The bounce handler is not triggering! Any ideas what could be causing the problem?
Does the bounce handler work with a custom domain? Or does it only work for appspotmail.com accounts?

Comment: Yes it works for custom domains that are configured with Google Apps accounts (well that's a requirement to be able to send mails in the first place). The only difference that I see is that we also have the `<security-constraint>` set: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/bounce

Comment: You can also send mail using the appspotmail.com account if you are not using a custom domain. Initially I had the security-contstraint but removed it to see if it worked without it. Thanks for the comment! Good to hear that it is actually working with Java for someone!!

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

- not all bounce types are getting passed to the app. It's easy to spot if your admin@ user is getting bounce notifications as emails to their inbox, but you see that `/_ah/bounce` was never triggered in your app logs. Try to send mail to non-existent user within your domain for test purposes.
- if you see `/_ah/bounce` was triggered, but the log is empty, ensure your `WEB-INF/logging.properties` defines appropriate logging level for bounce handling servlet. Should not be the case for `log.severe`, but still worth checking, since default GAE logging config omits anything below WARNING and people tend to log stuff with INFO severity.